# Disappearing answer content

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image: missing content]

After reading this answer, opening the top spoilers, scrolling down for a while and then scrolling back to this question, all the answer content had disappeared.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: It also happens to me with the iOS app on some questions *if the app has been opened for a while (days)*. I then force close the app and re-open, and the missing posts are back.

Comment: This is common on iOS when the content just fails to load. A refresh or restart is needed.

Comment: @AndrewL the content had already loaded and when scrolling back to it it had gone. If it is a loading issue as you suggest, it should be cached while on the page.

Comment: @RichieAHB It happens to me when I click on questions and loading is stunted. Sometimes it happens when it's fully loaded and I just reload the question

Comment: @AndrewL for me it was neither of those. It loaded, I read it, I scrolled down and scrolled back up. No reloading. It was a long page though so maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: @RichieAHB That also happens to me, but the most recent versions of the app don't seem to exhibit this behavior

Comment: @AndrewL interesting, although I seem to be up to date.

Comment: Just had this happen to me.